# How do I extract xml data for all products where a certain field has a certain value?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

The XML file contains a 1000 product entries. Some of them for the country Portugal.
I would like to get only the products where the country is Portugal and write that information into a new XML file onto my server.
How would I do that in PHP?

The XML content structure:

```
<products>
<product ID="38450">
    <name>Aparthotel Alfagar</name>
    <price currency="EUR">239.00</price>
    <URL>https://website.com/</URL>
    <images>
        <image>https://website.com/1.jpg</image>
        <image>https://website.com/2.jpg</image>
        <image>https://website.com/3.jpg</image>
    </images>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[<p>some text</p>]]>
    </description>
    <categories/>
    <properties>
        <property name="country">
            <value>Portugal</value>
        </property>
        <property name="lowestPrice">
            <value>239.00</value>
        </property>
        <property name="lowestPriceDate">
            <value>13-01-2020</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <variations/>
</product>
<!-- more product entries -->
```

My approuch started out as this:

```
    <?php
// Define source
$source_url = 'https://website.net/?encoding=utf-8&type=xml&id=';

// Define target
$file_url = '/home/website/public_html/media/';
$file_ext = '.xml';

// Load data
$array = simplexml_load_file($source_url.'654321');

// Filter data
$results_portugal = '';
foreach($array->product->properties->property->value['Portugal'] as $results) {

}

// Create datafiles
copy ($results_portugal,$file_url.'portugal'.$file_ext);
```

Obiously I got stuck pretty soon. Can anyone help me out please? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use XSLT? It'd be really simple with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch a part of an XML in SimpleXML or DOM using XPath expressions:

```
$products = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

var_dump(
  count(
    $products->xpath('//product[properties/property[@name = "country"]/value = "Portugal"]')
  )
);
var_dump(
  count(
    $products->xpath('//product[properties/property[@name = "country"]/value = "Spain"]')
  )
);
```

However here is no "nice" way to copy nodes in SimpleXML. DOM allows that:

```
// create source document and load XML
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);

// create target document and append root node
$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->appendChild($target->createElement('products'));

$expression = '//product[properties/property[@name = "country"]/value = "Portugal"]';

// iterate filtered nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $product) {
    // import node into target document and append
    $target->documentElement->appendChild(
        $target->importNode($product, TRUE)
    );
}

echo $target->saveXML();
```

For really large XMLs you need to use XMLReader/XMLWriter. They allow you to load only a part of the XML file into memory. Originally here is no easy way to copy nodes but I added this to [FluentDOM](https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM).

```
// Create the target writer and add the root element
$writer = new \FluentDOM\XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri('php://stdout');
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElement('products');

// load the source into a reader
$reader = new \FluentDOM\XMLReader();
$reader->open('data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($xml));

// iterate the product elements - the iterator expands them into a DOM node
foreach (new FluentDOM\XMLReader\SiblingIterator($reader, 'product') as $product) {
  /** @var \FluentDOM\DOM\Element $product */
  // validate country property
  if ($product('properties/property[@name = "country"]/value = "Portugal"')) {
    // write expanded node to the output
    $writer->collapse($product);
  }
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried several things with this. However, if I try your code in a php on my site and run it, the browser returns a HTTP ERROR 500. What could be the problem here?

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to develop and debug in a live/production environment. Try looking up the server error log file and increase the error reporting. If you don't have a local development environment, I suggest setting on up. Here is a live demo of the DOM example: https://3v4l.org/2biOD